# String start with # return with backslash in rails console in some case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In console of rails 4.2.7, I have the following test:

```
[45] pry(main)> '#$'
=> "\#$"
[46] pry(main)> '#@'
=> "\#@"
[47] pry(main)> '#!'
=> "#!"
[48] pry(main)> '#ab'
=> "#ab"
```

It seems rails will only put a "\" before the string when there is an @ or $ after #.

The problem leads me to this test is that I have a erb file that render a data attribute with an array of json:

```
data-xx="<%= [{xx: '#$', yy: 'yy'}.to_json, {zz: 'zzz'}.to_json] %>"
```

Then in chrome console, it will give the unexpected result as

```
$("#entry_show_modal_template").data('xx')
"["{\"xx\":\"\#$\",\"yy\":\"yy\"}", "{\"zz\":\"zzz\"}"]"
```

And when I change xx value from #! or some other string, the result will be ok as an array

```
$("#entry_show_modal_template").data('xx')
["{"xx":"#!","yy":"yy"}", "{"zz":"zzz"}"]
```

Does someone know if it is true and why it has such difference?
And it there any way to tackle this problem?

Comment: In ruby Console aa = [{xx: '#$', yy: 'yy'}, {zz: 'zzz'}].to_json   ===> In chrome console 

JSON.parse(aa), you will get expected array, its just ruby method to handle string interpolation thing

Comment: Thanks @WishZone. You are right. just put to_json in the array will fix the problem.

Comment: GREAT!! Just added answer , please mark it as solved

Comment: “put `to_json` in the array will fix the problem”—wrong. There is no problem, and hence `to_json` can not fix anything.

Comment: @mudasobwa yes there is no such issue but he is trying to get expected results, he will get in this way , you explaination is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mudasobwa's explaination is correct

According to your situation you should try in this way

===> In rails console

```
 json_values = [{xx: '#$', yy: 'yy'}, {zz: 'zzz'}].to_json
```

===> In chrome console

```
 result = JSON.parse(json_values)
```

you will get expected array, its just ruby technique to handle string interpolation thing

Answer (score 3):

This is not true.

In `'#{...}'` hash will also be escaped. This is done to prevent recursive/implicit *string interpolation*.

Look:

```
$a = 'hello'
"#$a"
#⇒ "hello"
```

The problem *is already solved by ruby for you*. Just use the produced string as is and don’t be fooled by the way it is *printed out in console*.

```
"\#$".length
#⇒ 2
"\#$" == '#$'
#⇒ true
"\#$"[0]
#⇒ "#"
```